# How the time based OTP varying between two devices even we using the same APP to generate OTP like google authenticator APP

Tags: one-time-password

I am having simple doubt on how the two way authentication works. I have tried google two way authentication for my gmail account. The OTP is generated by Google authenticator app. My doubt is how this app generating different OTP on different device even the users using same APP.

Comment: Please provide sample code to show what you are trying to do and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator can generate one time passwords based on HOTP or TOTP (see the RFC for more details).

HOTP is counter based. Each device will have its own counter, which will differ over time. Thus they will create different OTP values.

TOTP is time based. If the clocks of the devices differ, they will create different OTP values.

AND OF COURSE, if the devices were initialized with different seeds (QR-Codes), then the OTP values will also differ.

Comment: Thanks for explanantion